# Any Tex editor that supports Hoisting

Tags: editors

Is there any Latex editor which supports hoisting a section or subsection?
Most outlining softwares have hoisting feature. I don't find any Latex editor with hoisting feature. Any?

Note: Hoisting is not about collapsible  headings. It is about completely blocking out the rest of the text and zooming into one heading.

Here is a good example from FoldingText.

Collapsed headings look like this: 
[image]

Hoisted:

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "hoisting"?

Comment: "hoisting" seems to be a javascript idea. I don't understand what it might do in a LaTeX editor. Please provide an example showing what you would like to have. Just the name isn't enough.

Comment: Presumably you are looking for a collapsible outliner: certainly some of the entries in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides have such a feature

Comment: NO, it is not about collapsible headings. It is about zooming into a heading or section. The editor would hide the rest of the text outside of the heading. It is very useful to block out the rest of the text and focus on only a specific chapter/section/heading.

Comment: Here is an example using FoldingText: 
[1. unhoisted](https://monosnap.com/file/FhQUjajbyKg34DnnwOKw46woK1OsGL.png)


[2. Hoisted](https://monosnap.com/file/ic05y7WCl6ecEyIq01PN0uDYyYGtOu.png)

Comment: In Geany you can use `Document-Fold all`, then press, e.g., spacebar to unfold only the current block, then press backspace to undo the inserted space. You can make a macro out of this to use a single shortcut key.

Comment: is Geany Tex editor? I never heard of it.

Comment: Emacs has such a facility called [`outline-mode`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Outline-Mode.html).  It offers plenty of [`visibility commands`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Outline-Visibility.html#Outline-Visibility).

Comment: Geany is a general purpose programming editor, with IDE features such as a compile button, a document tree, etc. There are also specific plugins for LaTeX editing, for symbols, referencing, and so on. And it has code folding, which can be used for 'hoisting'.

Comment: `WinEdt` has the `Fold Node`, `Fold All` and `Fold Surrounding Nodes` functionalities.

Comment: I still remember the wonderfull  "hoisting" of FrameWork II ... (sometime seconds after the BigBang), but today I will suggest the outline panel of LyX. It is not a true LaTeX editor, and it does not collapse anything, but you can focus instantly any section, change their level or move it safely, without a dangerous cut & paste.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I am now trying to break down my file to focus on subsections. I don't think I will use Lyx. I need the standard Tex.

Comment: Emacs also has [narrowing](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Narrowing.html) — I think that's closer to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In TeXStudio you can find in the `View` menu:

1. `Collapse->Everything`

   [image]
2. And to expand the current block `Expand->Nearest Block`, however the coverage of this block can also be smaller then the whole subsection, if you are inside other collapse-able structures.

   [image]

It's also possible to assign keyboard shortcuts to these commands -- probably you can also do a macro which does both at once, but I did not test this.

---

Or totally different approach: Have every section in a separate file which is input into the main file. If you use `TeXstudio`s masterfile functionality, you can close all other files (including the main file) and concentrate on a single section.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am familiar with the Expand Everything feature of Texstudio.  I will do as you suggested.